# scope and an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  def good_publisher?
    self.articles.size > 50
  end

  scope :good_publishers, -> where { ...???? }
end
```

How do I express the `scope` through `good_publisher?`? Something like

`scope :good_publishers, -> where { x.good_publisher? }`

Comment: What did you mean by express the scope through good_publisher? method?

Comment: @Surya, I mean, use `user.good_publisher?` in `-> where { .... } `

Comment: `good_publisher?` is an instance method, while a scope creates class method, so no... there's no way you can use instance method in a scope. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Surya, calculate the total number of the "good_publishers".

Comment: No, I meant what are you planning to do with this scope? i.e. what are you intending to do with `User. good_publishers` and `user.good_publisher?` ?

Answer (score 2):

The scope has to be a SQL statement, your best bet here is to use a counter cache for the association.

At the `Article` class, include this:

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true # you should already have this belongs_to, all that needs to happen is include the counter_cache
```

Then, create a migration that includes the `articles_count` field to user:

```
add_column :users, :articles_count
```

Once you have this, the scope can be written as:

```
scope :good_publishers, where("articles_count > 50")
```